# How to create a Pre-Installed Windows 7 VHD

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machines

I am new into the world of servers. I was just working around creating a Windows 7 X64 Bootable VHD. Since my job profile makes me create windows 7 VMs every now and then, I want a pre-installed windows 7 VHD which I can simply attach in Hyper-v while I require it for testing. I may also use that VHD to dual boot inside my windows 8.1 Lenovo machine.

All I need is the installation to be skipped(or already completed) in that VHD.

Please Help!

Comment: So what have you tried? There are plenty of guides out there for creating VM templates, sysprepping windows, etc. and this site generally expects people to make more of an effort than "I need to do *x*, tell me how." Which is how you're coming across right now I'm afraid.

Comment: As @RobM pointed out, your question as it stands is way too broad and generic. I've flagged it accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do for your purposes, in my opinion, is:

1. Do a normal Windows 7 install in hyper-v.
2. Open an elevated command prompt and run `c:\windows\system32\sysprep\sysprep.exe /oobe /generalize /shutdown`
3. Delete the virtual machine but save the VHD.
4. Run machines based off [differencing disks](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720381%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) of that VHD for all of your purposes.

It'll make you do the out of box experience stuff (name this computer, give it a password, etc.) but that's it.